# Minecraft pymclevel replacement that supports Anvil maps?

Tags: python, minecraft, topology

It is apparent that so far the Anvil support for pymclevel is still not complete.  Projects such as [TopoMC](https://github.com/mathuin/TopoMC) very much are in need of this support for creating worlds that are compliant with the new map standards that take advantage of 256 height.

A bounty (at $110 USD) for full Anvil support has apparently been put into play and the issue has been outlined [here](https://github.com/mcedit/pymclevel/issues/78), however no one seems to have taken up the torch fully (just a start has begun, but not finalized).

***Are there any other options that exist aside from `pymclevel` that can be used in its place for TopoMC***?  The author [is very interested](https://github.com/mathuin/TopoMC/issues/8#issuecomment-7958110) in getting this in place, however we've both been at a standstill of really finding any replacements and I thought I should make an inquiry to see if anyone else may be familiar with other existent options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been rendered moot, as pymclevel now supports Anvil maps.